# HttpWebRequest Timeouts After Ten Consecutive Requests

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a web crawler for a specific site. The application is a VB.Net Windows Forms application that is *not* using multiple threads - each web request is consecutive. However, after ten successful page retrievals every successive request times out.

I have reviewed the similar questions already posted here on SO, and have implemented the recommended techniques into my GetPage routine, shown below:

```
Public Function GetPage(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    Dim uri As New Uri(url)
    Dim sp As ServicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri)
    sp.ConnectionLimit = 100

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.KeepAlive = False
    request.Timeout = 15000

    Try
        Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
            Using dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
                    If response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                        Throw New Exception("Got response status code: " + response.StatusCode)
                    End If
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
            response.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim msg As String = "Error reading page """ & url & """. " & ex.Message
        Logger.LogMessage(msg, LogOutputLevel.Diagnostics)
    End Try

    Return result

End Function
```

Have I missed something? Am I not closing or disposing of an object that should be? It seems strange that it always happens after ten consecutive requests.

Notes:

1. In the constructor for the class in which this method resides I have the following:

   ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100
2. If I set KeepAlive to true, the timeouts begin after five requests.
3. All the requests are for pages in the same domain.

**EDIT**

I added a delay between each web request of between two and seven seconds so that I do not appear to be "hammering" the site or attempting a DOS attack. However, the problem still occurs.

Comment: What is the product name and version of the web server that is hosting the app?

Comment: There is a 10 connection limit to IIS 5

Comment: I'm curious - did you ever nail down the cause?  I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @James: No, never did get to the crux of the matter. That's why I accepted the Denial of Service (DOS) protection since it was the only remaining answer that made any sense.

Comment: I'm getting a very similar issue hitting the twitter API with HttpWebRequest.  Even stranger it won't happen when I run fiddler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the site has some sort of DOS protection, which kicks in when it's hit with a number of rapis requests. You may want to try setting the UserAgent on the webrequest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If DOS protection is the cause, why the difference in timeouts when KeepAlive is true vs. when KeepAlive is false?

Comment: Setting UserAgent improved the situation. I'm still getting some timeouts but they're more random and not nearly as frequent. So before I mark this as correct can you expand your answer to indicate why setting UserAgent has this effect?

Comment: After further testing, it helps a little but I still eventually get a timeout on a page and all successive pages, so I'm starting to believe the DOS protection theory.

Comment: I don't think DoS protection is the answer - see my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today and my resolution was to ensure that the response was closed at all times.

I think that you need to put in a response.Close() before you throw your exception inside the using.

```
Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse) 
        Using dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream() 
            Using reader As New StreamReader(dataStream) 
                If response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then 
                    response.Close()  
                    Throw New Exception("Got response status code: " + response.StatusCode) 
                End If 
                result = reader.ReadToEnd() 
            End Using 
        End Using 
        response.Close() 
    End Using
```

Comment: @Geoff: the `Using response` ensures response gets closed.

Comment: @Geoff: I gave it a try anyway, but it didn't help. I believe John is correct - the `Using response` should take care of closing things properly. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Let me just comment that John's comment provided a solution for me (having a similar problem--timeouts after subsequent requests).

Comment: sticking the HttpWebResponse into a using statement fixed it for me.  I must have been leaving the object open in one of the logic branches.  FYI - I was getting stuck at about 70 requests before the timeouts would hit me.  If I immediately closed and re-ran the application, I'd again get to 70.  It was not a problem that manifested on localhost for me, just when accessing remote servers.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following solution and it works for me.  Hope it helps to you too.

Declare "global" on the form the variables.

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse;
```

Then always use `myHttpWebResponse.Close();` after each connection.

```
myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had this problem myself (due to my target environment using 4.0 and not allowing any external assembly references)

I did some digging however and found a fix of sorts and is very interesting from a .NET inner-workings perspective

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

ServicePointManager internally handles the actual HTTP request created by multiple HttpWebRequest objects ..problem is, these don’t get closed automatically and HttpWebRequest doesn’t gets garbage collected immediately

So I found something very interesting – if I make HttpWebRequest an instance level variable AND I force garbage collection after switching the reference out …it works (without the DefaultConnectionLimit = 100 hack)

```
private HttpWebRequest Request { get; set; }

public void MyMethod() {
   Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://myUrl");
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
}
```

Before I was creating a new local variable each time in the method. This seemed to fix my problem - probably a little too late to help you but thought I'd share in case anyone else comes across this

Answer (score 1):

If the server is using a database and does not close each database connection properly, you may receive an error (e.g. statuscode 502) when the max. connection limited is reached (until the database connection timeout). 
A solution in this case is only to 'sleep' the webrequest thread for a given time.
Furthermore you should ensure that each request and reponse stream is being closed after processing (in best case by using of an 'Using' statement):

Answer (score 0):

myRequest.Connection = "Close"; 
will make the server close the connection which will make the connection manager close the connection too.

Comment: Thanks Tymek. I added this to my code but it throws an exception that says "Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property. Parameter name: value". I've found little via Google regarding what this means. Did you run across this problem? If so, how did you correct it?